# How to completely remove MySQL files from my windows computer

Tags: php, mysql, apache-http-server

I have recently installed apache, php, and mysql. Apache and php are configured properly, but when I tried to configure mysql it shows that there is already a security file for mysql that is setup and it is not allowing me to modify the security settings.

I unselected the modify security settings and completed the installaton and configuration, but when I checked it, it is not configured with php so I removed the MySQL instance and re-installed. Same problem is occuring everytime.

I want to completely remove the MySQL security or configuration files from the computer. Can anyone help me how to remove the MySQL configuration files completely?

Comment: not programming related...

Comment: What flavor OS you running?  Also, this may be better suited for stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your instance using the Instance Config Wizard, then uninstall mySQL, and delete the directory from your root folder.